# Load visible HTML on DIV with a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Rookie question. I want to know if it is possible to insert HTML to a Div or any other element and make it visible on the source.

For example, if I use the jQuery load() function I can load the HTML source, but if I click on "view page source", the HTML is not visible.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>load demo</title>
<style>
 body {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: Arial;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <b>Products:</b>
 <ol id="all-products"></ol>

 <script>
  $( "#all-products" ).load( "index2.html #products li" );
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Is there some workaround to having dynamically inserted HTML code visible on the "view page source" option?

Thanks,

RH

Comment: please add the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: You can insert HTML into a DIV via load and it will be visible via inspect element, but not via view source. View source doesn't show dynamic data.

Comment: Can you describe your purpose for "seeing it in the source"?  The reason i ask is that it will show in the the source of "inspect element" in dev tools.  It will not show in the static, single-load source.  You might mention what browser you are using.  In both Chrome and Firefox, right click and choose "Inspect Element" to inspect a "live source" that will reflect js updates.

Comment: [What Is The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: *"View source"* only shows what was sent from server and does not change with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers run JavaScript "client-side" (meaning the code executes on your machine, not the server that sent it to you). And, for security reasons, JavaScript in a browser isn't allowed to access the file system (can you imagine the havoc that would ensue if it could?).

So no. You can't write JavaScript that updates the source file that it came from.

You could have some JavaScript, make a request back to the server for some "server-side" code (code that is executed on the server like: .php, ASP.NET, .jsp) to execute. Those server-side architectures are allowed access to the server file system.